# Restricting D-Bus access to the logged-in user via ConsoleKit or systemd

Tags: linux, dbus, systemd

I need to restrict the client of a D-Bus service to only the user logged into the system locally, via ConsoleKit or systemd. How must I configure or write the D-Bus service to do so?

Comment: If coding a D-Bus service if off-topic in a coding website, then could someone please tell me where it *would* be on-topic?

Comment: At best guess some linux forum or authors - but I see nothing wrong with this question, so you have my re-open vote

Comment: Your question is [off-topic in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).